# IE7 doesn't play well with p tags and JWPlayer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, jwplayer

Today I was setting up JWPlayer , and I noticed a bug in IE6 and 7 only - the videos wouldn't display on the page when the `<video>` tags were wrapped in a `<p>` tag. The videos display fine as long as they're not enclosed in a `<p>`. When they're wrapped in `<p>` tags they're just a blank white block.

The client likes to wrap their videos in a p tag for spacing, so I need to either figure out a way around it, or find an explanation of why this can't be done. Any ideas?

To my knowledge, there isn't anything in the CSS that could possibly cause this, though I plan to comb through it and check tomorrow.

Code here (there are multiple players on any given page):

```
    <p>
      <video id="video1" class="JWVideo" width="276" height="206" style="background:transparent !important;" src="/ext/resources/video/index/Video-1.mp4"></video>
    </p>
    <script>
      $('.JWVideo').each(function(){
        var source = $(this).attr("src");
                    jwplayer(this.id).setup({
                      stretching: "fill",
                      flashplayer: "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
                      controlbar: "false",
                      levels: [
                        {file: source}
                      ]
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

Comment: I've confirmed it's definitely NOT the css, and it happens regardless of which tag I use for the source video, `video` or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.  Changing the video code to use a 'div' with a 'data' parameter for the source seems to get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Video` tag is a a part of html5 specification and it never works in IE 6 and 7. Try viewing the same page in firefox or Chrome, that support the video tag and see how the `p` tag affects rendering.

Comment: It affects other tags, it's not limited to the video tag. Rewriting the code to use an a tag instead has the same effect, and it *only* happens when the source tag is enclosed in a `<p>`.